# How to solve "Array has incomplete element type" in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, cs50

I have been working on `CS50` where I'm doing `struct` to allow user to input and save it in an array. However, I get

> array has incomplete element type struct person

Below here is the program I'm working on:

**Phonebook.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 4

typedef struct  
{
    char name[20];
    char number[8];
}person;

int main ()
{
    struct person ppl[MAX];
    int i;
    
    for(i = 0;i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        printf("\nEnter details of user %d\n\n", i+1);
        
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", ppl[i].name);
        
        printf("Enter phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", ppl[i].number);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Name\tPhone Number\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\n", ppl[i].name, ppl[i].number);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Error Stacktrace**

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    Phonebook.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o Phonebook
Phonebook.c:15:22: error: array has incomplete element type 'struct person'
    struct person ppl[MAX];
                     ^
Phonebook.c:15:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct person'
    struct person ppl[MAX];
           ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: Phonebook] Error 1
```

How do I solve this issue? Please enlighten me on this

Answer (score 3):

`person` is a typedef to an unnamed struct. `struct person` doesn't exist.

Either omit the `struct` prefix: `person ppl[MAX];`

Or give the unnamed struct a name: `typedef struct people`  (at this point you can remove the typedef if you want to refer to the struct as `struct people` instead of `people`)

Comment: Or remove the `typedef` entirely: `struct person { ... }`